# ubuntu server rename file with dot

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, rename

Ubuntu Server 11.10

How to rename file ".test" to "test" ?

```
rename .test test
```

Error appears: syntax error at (eval 1) line 1, near "."

Comment: Rename is used to replace the first occurence of a string in a filename with a specified pattern: to see how it should be used look here: http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename - what you want to do is achieved by mv as larsmans already pointed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `mv(1)` command to rename files.

```
mv .test test
```